# How does a multitasking android application with floating dialog work?

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, multitasking

Have come across few Android applications that can display a Dialog on foreground, that is not from the currently active foreground Activity, but perhaps from a background service (if I get the notion right). There is a floating browser, floating note-taker etc. The dialog is an interactive one, i.e. it has buttons that can pressed, text area which can be edited etc. They usually have a translucent background, through which you can partly see the underlying foreground Activity. They floating dialog does not prohibit the foreground Activity's controls (buttons, text area etc.) from functioning i.e. they remain clickable and editable.

- How can this effect of multitasking be achieved ?
- Do they need some special permissions ?
- Are there certain applications that can prohibit such floating dialogs from showing up ?
- Does the mechanism work in all versions of Android or limited to older or newer versions only ?

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest you have to declare this permission.And every thing remains same as alert  dialog as above.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />



AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    builder.setTitle("App Addicted");
    builder.setMessage(profileDetails.getProfilename() + " profile will be activates with in " + mPreference_Service.getInt(IConstants.ALERT_NOTIFICATION_TIME, 0)
            + " minute(s)");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Change", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddProfileActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra(IConstants.KEY_HOMESCREENTOSHOWAPPS, true);
            intent.putExtra(IConstants.PROFILE_NAME, profileDetails.getProfilename());
            startActivity(intent);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog aDialog = builder.create();
    aDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    aDialog.show();
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I see a positiveButton and a negativeButton being built. I wonder if I can add other buttons, editable TextArea etc. ? Anyhow, I am going to try this out.